# Troubleshooting errors with multiple joins where one table has a minimum value for the variable in the group-by statement

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

I've got a practice question for a SQL user exam that is asking me to return three column from a combination of four different tables, but I'm only returning the first row in time for patient ID's that are in a group by statement.

Here's what I have:

```
select p.patient_nm as 'Patient Name', d.code as 'Diagnosis Code', convert(date, e.start_dts) as 'Encounter Date'
from
(with added_row_number as (select *, row_number() over(partition by patient_id order by start_dts) as row_number
from encounters
)
select encounter_id, patient_id, start_dts
from added_row_number 
where row_number=1) e

left join edw_emr_ods.patients p
on e.patient_id=p.patient_id
left join edw_emr_ods.encounter_diagnoses ed
on e.encounter_id=ed.encounter_id
left join edw_emr_ods.diagnoses d
on ed.diagnosis_id=d.diagnosis_id
```

It seems to have a problem with this portion of the code, which I got and adapted from some other site, when I searched for info on how to return just the first row in a 'group-by' group

```
with added_row_number as (select *, row_number() over(partition by patient_id order by start_dts) as row_number
from encounters
)
select encounter_id, patient_id, start_dts
from added_row_number 
where row_number=1
```

I don't get any errors when I run just this piece, and it returns the bare minimum I need to join the three other tables, so I can return the three required variables.  Here's what it looks like when I run just that piece:

[image]

But these are the errors I'm getting when I run the whole thing:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 280
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 280
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 285
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I've tried inserting a lone semicolon and a couple different places, but none of them work.

This code seems like it should be one of the most computationally efficient ways of returning this table.

If this isn't the way to go, please let me know what the best code would be, preferably without the use of a temporary table.

Thanks

**EDIT:**  based on a comment, I'm trying to change that smaller piece of code into a subquery, but am still getting an error:

```
(select encounter_id, patient_id, start_dts, row_number() over(partition by patient_id order by start_dts) visitnum
from edw_emr_ods.encounters
where visitnum=1) e
```

Produces the error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 298
Invalid column name 'visitnum'.
```

If I omit the where clause, the subquery works, but it returns all of the rows, when I need just those when 'visitnum' is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with` is a common table expression, and it can't be used inside a sub-query. Just convert it to a regular sub-query.

And you can't reference a column alias in the same context as you create it, aside for in an `order by`. So you need an additional sub-query/derived table.

```
(
  select encounter_id, patient_id, start_dts
  from (
    select encounter_id, patient_id, start_dts, row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by start_dts) visitnum
    from edw_emr_ods.encounters
  ) e1
  where visitnum = 1
) e
```